# How to define the range 'r(n,)' using a variable in match() function with awk

Tags: bash, awk, fasta

I am processing text files with thousands of records per file. Each record is made up of two lines: a header that starts with ">" and followed by a line with a long string of characters "-AGTCNR".
Here is how a simple file looks like:

```
>ACML500-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_-2
----TAAGATTTTGACTTCTTCCCCCATCATCAAGAAGAATTGT-------
>ACRJP458-10|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
-----------TCCCTTTAATACTAGGAGCCCCTGACATAGCCTTTCCTAAATAAT-----
>ASILO303-17|Dip|gs-Par|sp-Par vid|subsp-NA|co
-----TAAGATTCTGATTACTCCCCCCCTCTCTAACTCTTCTTCTTCTATAGTAGATG
>ASILO326-17|Dip|gs-Goe|sp-Goe par|subsp-NA|c
TAAGATTTTGATTATTACCCCCTTCATTAACCAGGAACAGGATGA------
>CLT100-09|Lep|gs-Col|sp-Col elg|subsp-NA|co-Buru
AACATTATATTTGGAATTT-------GATCAGGAATAGTCGGAACTTCTCTGAA------
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAAACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT
>STBOD057-09|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
ATCTAATATTGCACATAGAGGAACCTCNGTATTTTTTCTCTCCATCT------TTAG
>TBBUT582-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
-----CCCCCTCATTAACATTACTAAGTTGAAAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>TBBUT583-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTCATTAA----------------AATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>AFBTB001-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGCTCCATCC-------------TAGAAAGAGGGG---------GGGTGA
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTAGGAAATTGATTAGTACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT---
>AFBTB003-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTTCTGC------CATGAGAAAGA-------------AGGGTGA
>AFBTB002-09|Cole|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
-------TCTTCTGCTCAT-------GGGGCAGGAACAGGG----------TGA
>ACRJP458-10|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
-----------TCCCTTTAATACTAGGAGCCCCTTTCCT----TAAATAAT-----
```

Now I am trying to search through the second field (line) of each record and only extract records which have up to a certain maximum number of "-" characters (referred to as gaps) at the beginning `$start_gaps` and end, `$end_gaps`, of line(field $2).

I have tried a few codes and the following came works well:

```sh
read -p "Please enter the muximum number of gaps allowed at start position: " start_gaps &&
read -p "Please enter the maximum number of gaps allowed at the end position: " end_gaps &&
awk -v start_g=$start_gaps -v end_g=$end_gaps 'BEGIN{
RS="\n>"; FS="\n"; ORS="\n"; OFS="\n"; }; (x=start_g+1)(y=end_g+1) { 
if ( match($2, "^-{5,}") && match($2, "-{6,}$") ) {
next} else {print x y ">"$0}}' infile > outfile
```

But I need to keep using variable numbers without explicitly editing the script every time i am conducting the regex pattern matching. So i tried the following but the regex do not accept variables. What is the best work around to this?

```sh
read -p "Please enter the muximum number of gaps allowed at start position: " start_gaps &&
read -p "Please enter the maximum number of gaps allowed at the end position: " end_gaps &&
awk -v start_g=$start_gaps -v end_g=$end_gaps 'BEGIN{
RS="\n>"; FS="\n"; ORS="\n"; OFS="\n"; }; (x=start_g+1)(y=end_g+1) {
if ( match($2, "^-{x,}") && match($2, "-{y,}$") ) {
next} else {print x y ">"$0}}' infile > outfile
```

Expected results:

```
>ASILO303-17|Dip|gs-Par|sp-Par vid|subsp-NA|co  
-----TAAGATTCTGATTACTCCCCCCCTCTCTAACTCTTCTTCTTCTATAGTAGATG
>ASILO326-17|Dip|gs-Goe|sp-Goe par|subsp-NA|c
TAAGATTTTGATTATTACCCCCTTCATTAACCAGGAACAGGATGA------
>CLT100-09|Lep|gs-Col|sp-Col elg|subsp-NA|co-Buru
AACATTATATTTGGAATTT-------GATCAGGAATAGTCGGAACTTCTCTGAA------
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAAACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT
>STBOD057-09|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
ATCTAATATTGCACATAGAGGAACCTCNGTATTTTTTCTCTCCATCT------TTAG
>TBBUT582-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
-----CCCCCTCATTAACATTACTAAGTTGAAAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>TBBUT583-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTCATTAA----------------AATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>AFBTB001-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGCTCCATCC-------------TAGAAAGAGGGG---------GGGTGA
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTAGGAAATTGATTAGTACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT---
>AFBTB003-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTTCTGC------CATGAGAAAGA-------------AGGGTGA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match` sets variable `RLENGTH` to the matched substring's length, make use of it. Also, you don't need a multi-char `RS` for this.

```
awk -v start_g="$start_gaps" -v end_g="$end_gaps" '
/^>/ { hdr=$0; next }
match($0,/^-*/) && RLENGTH<=start_g && match($0,/-*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_g { print hdr; print }
' file
```

Comment: unfortunately the code seems not to interpret `&&` well and it looks like it matches only one end. I have managed to improve on my code to accommodate variables: `awk -v start_g=$start_gaps -v end_g=$end_gaps ' /^>/ { hdr=$0; next }; (x="^-{"start_g+1",}")(y="-{"end_g+1",}$") { if ( match($0, x) && match($0, y) ) {next} else {print x y hdr; print }}' infile | less`. But still i get what seems to be one end being matched in some cases.

Comment: IT WORKS,however, I struggled but finally managed to understand the inclusion of `*` in `/^-*/` and `/-*$/`

Comment: What of a case where the matching specifically targets the middle of a line? `awk -v start_N=$start_Ns -v mid_N=$mid_Ns -v end_N=$end_Ns ' /^>/ { hdr=$0; next }; match($0,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=start_N && match($0,/[Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=mid_N && match($0,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_N { print hdr; print }' $input_file` doesn't really work