# Is there a way to use a variable in to define range in awk match() function 'match($0,/r{0,var}/)'

Tags: regex, awk, fasta

I am processing text files with thousands of records per file. Each record is made up of two lines: a header that starts with `>` and followed by a line with a long string of characters `-AGTCNR`. The two lines make a complete record.
Here is how a simple file looks like:

```
>ACML500-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_-2
----TAAGATTTTGACTTCTTCCCCCATCATCAAGAAGAATTGT-------NNNN
>ACRJP458-10|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
--------NNNTCCCTTTAATACTAGGAGCCCCTGACATAGCCTTTCCTAAATAAT-----
>ASILO303-17|Dip|gs-Par|sp-Par vid|subsp-NA|co
-----TAAGATTCTGATTACTCCCCCCCTCTCTAACTCTTCTTCTTCTATAGTAGATG
>ASILO326-17|Dip|gs-Goe|sp-Goe par|subsp-NA|c
TAAGATTTTGATTATTACCCCCTTCATTAACCAGGAACAGGATGA------
>CLT100-09|Lep|gs-Col|sp-Col elg|subsp-NA|co-Buru
AACATTATATTTGGAANNN-------GATCAGGAATAGTCGGAACTTCTCTGAA------
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAAACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT
>STBOD057-09|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
ATCTAATATTGCACATAGAGGAACCTCNGTATTTTTTCTCTCCATCT------TTAG
>TBBUT582-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
-----CCCCCTCATTAACATTACTAAGTTGAAAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>TBBUT583-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTCATTAA--NNAGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>AFBTB001-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGCTCCATCC-------------TAGAAAGAGGGG---------GGGTGA
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTAGGAAATTGATTAGTACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT---
>AFBTB003-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTTCTGC------CATGAGAAAGA-------------AGGGTGA
>AFBTB002-09|Cole|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
-------TCTTCTGCTCAT-------GGGGCAGGAACAGGG----------TGA
>ACRJP458-10|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
NNNNNNNNNNNTCCCTTTAATACTAGGAGCCCCTTTCCT----TAAATAAT-----
```

With the following code I can search through the second line, that contains the string of characters, for each record and extract records which have up to a certain maximum number of `-` or `N` or `n` characters at the beginning of line using `$start_gaps` variable and end of line using `$end_gaps` variable, this is done in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276934/how-to-define-the-range-rn-using-a-variable-in-match-function-with-awk):

```sh
start_Ns=10
end_Ns=10
awk -v start_N=$start_Ns -v end_N=$end_Ns ' /^>/ {
hdr=$0; next }; match($0,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=start_N && 
match($0,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_N {
 print hdr; print }' infile.aln > without_shortseqs.aln
```

Now i need to search for the occurrence of `-` or `N` or `n` characters in the region "not including" the beginning or end terminals of the second line for every record and filter out records with more than a specific maximum number of `-` or `N` or `n` characters. The code below does it but i need to use a variable that i can easily reset:

```sh
start_Ns=10
end_Ns=10
awk -v start_N=10 -v end_N=10 ' /^>/ { 
hdr=$0; next }; match($0,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=start_N &&
match($0,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_N && match($0,/N{0,11}/) { 
print hdr; print }' infile.aln > without_shortseqs_mids.aln
```

As for a variable i tried the following but failed:

```sh
awk -v start_N=10 -v mid_N=11 -v end_N=10 ' /^>/ { 
hdr=$0; next }; match($0,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=start_N &&
match($0,/N{0,mid_N}/) && match($0,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_N { 
print hdr; print }' infile.aln > without_shortseqs_mids.aln
```

Expected results:

```
>ASILO303-17|Dip|gs-Par|sp-Par vid|subsp-NA|co
-----TAAGATTCTGATTACTCCCCCCCTCTCTAACTCTTCTTCTTCTATAGTAGATG
>ASILO326-17|Dip|gs-Goe|sp-Goe par|subsp-NA|c
TAAGATTTTGATTATTACCCCCTTCATTAACCAGGAACAGGATGA------
>CLT100-09|Lep|gs-Col|sp-Col elg|subsp-NA|co-Buru
AACATTATATTTGGAANNN-------GATCAGGAATAGTCGGAACTTCTCTGAA------
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAAACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT
>STBOD057-09|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
ATCTAATATTGCACATAGAGGAACCTCNGTATTTTTTCTCTCCATCT------TTAG
>TBBUT582-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
-----CCCCCTCATTAACATTACTAAGTTGAAAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA
>AFBTB001-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGCTCCATCC-------------TAGAAAGAGGGG---------GGGTGA
>PMANL2431-12|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_
----ATGCCTATTAGGAAATTGATTAGTACCTTTAATATT----CCGAAT---
>AFBTB003-09|Col|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Ethi|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTTCTGC------CATGAGAAAGA-------------AGGGTGA
```

Comment: Instead of the notation `/ere/` you can use `"ere"`. This way you could write `"N{0," mid_N "}"`. As an example. Be aware, that in this case, you could end up with some complex quoting issues.

Comment: the `/.../` are regex constants that don't allow variable substitution

Comment: If this is FASTA format you should probably say so, and tag this with [tag:fasta]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Perhaps accept the answer and articulate a new question with a clear problem statement, ideally much simpler.

Comment: `$start_Ns` targets the beginning of the sequence, `$end_Ns` targets the terminal end of the sequence and `mid_Ns` is meant to target the region from he second to second last nucleotide in a sequence, given that these three variables may be assigned different values like `start_Ns=10`, `mid_Ns=7` and `end_Ns=10`.All this in FASTA format of course

Comment: I probably don't know enough about nucleotides to understand that properly, but could you split up the entire line with `substr()` (perhaps based on where the start_Ns and end_Ns are found, if not absolute positions)?

Comment: @tripleee "nucleotide" means the same as "character" in this case `-AGTCNR`. Great help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following logic in order not to overcomplicate things.

1. Search the beginning part, remove it from the string
2. Search the end part, remove it from the string
3. Search the middle part in the remainder:

```sh
awk -v start_N=10 -v mid_N=11 -v end_N=10 '
   /^>/{hdr=$0; next}
   { seq=$0 }
   match(seq,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH > start_N { next }
   { seq=substr(seq,RSTART+RLENGTH) }
   match(seq,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH > end_N { next }
   { seq=substr(seq,1,RSTART-1) }
   { while (match(seq,/[-Nn]+/)) { 
        if(RLENGTH>mid_N) next
        seq=substr(seq,RSTART+RLENGTH)
     }
   }
   { print hdr; print $0 }' file
```

An alternative method would be  making use of Extended Regular expressions with character duplication:

```sh
awk -v start_N=10 -v mid_N=11 -v end_N=10 '
   (FNR==1) { ere_start = "^[-Nn]{" start_N+1 ",}"
              ere_end = "[-Nn]{" mid_N+1 ",}$"
              ere_mid = "[^-Nn][-Nn]{" end_N+1 ",}[^-Nn]"
   /^>/{hdr=$0; next}
   { seq=$0 }
   match(seq,ere_start) { next }
   match(seq,ere_end) { next }
   match(seq,ere-mid) { next }
   { print hdr; print $0 }' file
```

Comment: Works well. One remaining problem is it fails to remove `>TBBUT583-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N
TAAGATTTTGACTCATTAA--NNAGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA` which has two instanceses of 'N' strings within the sequence

Comment: @Kibet are you implying that the characters `-Nn` should not be consequitive?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have explained better. I am trying to filter out records with more than 11 $mid_N. Such that, as for the case of `>TBBUT583-11|Lep|gs-NA|sp-NA|subsp-NA|co-Buru|site-NA|lat_N TAAGATTTTGACTCATTAA--NNAGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAATGGAGCAGGAACAGGATGA`, it should be excluded because it has two instances of the regex first at `--NN`, RLENGTH =4 and secondly at `NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN`, RLENGTH=15. since the maximum allowed is RLENGTH of 11, this record is removed from the output. The ingenious use of `substr()` in your approach is outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string as the second argument to `match` and then the regular string interpolation operators in Awk work fine.

```
awk -v start_N=10 -v mid_N=11 -v end_N=10 ' /^>/ {
        hdr=$0; next }
    match($0,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=start_N &&
        match($0,"N{0," mid_N "}") &&
            match($0,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_N {
        print hdr; print }'
```

Just to spell this out a bit, if you use `/regex/` then the text between the slashes is immediately interpreted as a regular expression, but if you use `"regex"` or a piece of code which evaluates to a string, the regular Awk string-handling functions are processed first, and only then is the resulting string interpreted as a regular expression.

Comment: This will fail. if you have a line `NNNAGATANNN`, this match will fail as the middle part will match the beginning again. `---AGATANNN`, here the middle part will match the end again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. In my humble opinion, you should rephrase a bit your question and make sure your objective is 100% clear to all potential readers of this thread.

With regards to having a variable inside a construct in which awk doesn't allow the use of a variable, there is a standard trick that would apply whichever scripting tool you would use (e.g. sed or even some more complex stuff in perl or Python): **interrupt your awk script by breaking the single-quote construct, and you insert in there a variable expansion that is performed by the shell, *not* by awk**. For instance, here, you would define `mid_N` in Bash and then use `"${mid_N}"` in the middle of your awk script, with a closing single quote immediately before and a (re-)opening single quote immediately after. Like so:

```
mid_N=11
awk -v start_N=10 -v end_N=10 ' /^>/ { 
hdr=$0; next }; match($0,/^[-Nn]*/) && RLENGTH<=start_N &&
match($0,/N{0,'"${mid_N}"'}/) && match($0,/[-Nn]*$/) && RLENGTH<=end_N { 
print hdr; print }' infile.aln > without_shortseqs_mids.aln
```

That's a minimal-edit solution to the specific issue you mentioned below your "As for a variable i tried the following but failed:"